# PyQt4: Auto completion in Qscintilla and horizontal scrolling

Tags: python, autocomplete, scroll, pyqt4, qscintilla

I want to show all attributes and tags in auto completion list of a html file if auto completion threshold is set to 1. I have tried this code to use APIs i set this code after the file is loaded in new mdi child(sub window) but it is not working:

```
lexer=Qsci.QsciLexerHTML()
api = Qsci.QsciAPIs(lexer)
## Add autocompletion strings
api.add("aLongString")
api.add("aLongerString")
api.add("aDifferentString")
api.add("sOmethingElse")
## Compile the api for use in the lexer
api.prepare()
self.activeMdiChild().setAutoCompletionSource(Qsci.QsciScintilla.AcsAPIs)
self.activeMdiChild().setLexer(lexer)
```

and my horizontal scroll bar is visible all the time i want to set it as scrollbarasneeded. please tell how to do these two tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Other than failing to set the [auto-completion threshold](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a508eb34df3030ac28321b12d86d6670c), there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your example code. Here's a minimal working example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qsci

class Window(Qsci.QsciScintilla):
    def __init__(self):
        Qsci.QsciScintilla.__init__(self)
        lexer = Qsci.QsciLexerHTML(self)
        api = Qsci.QsciAPIs(lexer)
        api.add('aLongString')
        api.add('aLongerString')
        api.add('aDifferentString')
        api.add('sOmethingElse')
        api.prepare()
        self.setAutoCompletionThreshold(1)
        self.setAutoCompletionSource(Qsci.QsciScintilla.AcsAPIs)
        self.setLexer(lexer)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The scrollbar-as-needed feature cannot really be solved, unless you are willing to reimplement everything yourself (which would not be easy). The underlying Scintilla control doesn't directly support automatic horizontal scrollbar hiding, because it involves a potentially very expensive calculation (i.e. determining the longest line). Most people who use Scintilla/Qscintilla just learn to put up with the ever-present horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: can you tell me how to load api from a file like .xml or anything and which types of files are used in load() method of apis.

Comment: This post saved me, because it turns out (at least in latest PyQt) that it is *essential* to give self as param to the lexer, so if you just write `lexer = Qsci.QsciLexerHTML(self)` the added API items will not show up. So although http://www.kidstrythisathome.com/2011/08/autocompletion-using-pyqt4-and-qscintilla/ looked promising I could not get it to work!